# Rspec yield in let helper

Tags: ruby, rspec-rails

As in the title. Is there possibility to yield something to 'let'? Like here:

```
let(:call_request) { post :create, article: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(yield) }
```

When I'm trying to use it:

```
it 'creates a new article' do
  expect { call_request { :article } }.to change(Article, :count).by(1)
end
```

It says:

```
ArticlesController POST create when admin signed in with valid attributes creates a new article
     Failure/Error: let(:call_request) { post :create, article: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(yield) }

     LocalJumpError:
       no block given (yield)
     # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:61:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can I somehow do that? Maybe syntax is wrong or there is smarter way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a method:

```
def call_request
  post :create, article: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(yield)
end
```

The only difference between `let` and a normal method is that `let` declarations are memoized per example.  Since you intend to pass a block to it, the memoization isn't appropriate, anyway, and a method def will work better.